# Is there a way to reload a specific ResourceBundle?

Tags: java, jsf-2, resourcebundle

I have a custom database-backed `ResourceBundle` that needs to be reloaded sometimes.
I do not want to use `ResourceBundle.clearCache()` because it reloads all the bundles.

Is it possible to reload just one bundle?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to ask here. You are using custom implementation of ResourceBundle? And you still don't know how to reaload it?

Comment: Sorry, I made a stupid question. I just made a `reload()` method and call it every insert/edit/remove operation. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is part of the Java API since 1.6.  Start by getting the handle to the bundle you want to reload:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyResources", new Locale("fr", "CH"),
                        ResourceBundle.Control.getControl(FORMAT_PROPERTIES));
```

You can set the time to live for the bundle and allow the loader to reload it for you.  You can read all about this in the Java API [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html).